# I can't plot my rejection sampling histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram, sampling

My target PDF is the following:

[image: f(x) = 4x/pi^2, for 0 <= x <= pi/2,]

and  0 elsewhere.

My proposal PDF is

[image]

My code is the following:

```
f= function(x) {
  if (x >= 0 & x <= pi/2) {
    return((4/pi^2)*x)
  } else if (x > pi/2 & x <= pi) {
    return(4/pi - (4/pi^2)*x)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}


g = function(x) {
  if (x >= pi/2 && x <= pi) {
    return(sin(x)/2)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }}


M <- max(f(x)/g(x))


rejection_sampling <- function(n) {
  samples <- numeric(n)
  i <- 1
  while (i <= n) {
    x <- runif(1, min = 0, max = pi)
    u <- runif(1)
    if (u <= f(x)/(M*g(x))) {
      samples[i] <- x} 
    else{
      i <- i + 1
  }
  return(samples)
}


samples <- rejection_sampling(1000)
hist(samples, breaks=50)
```

When I run the line " samples <- rejection_sampling(1000)", I get the error message

```
Error in if (u <= f(x)/(M * g(x))) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Running the line "M <- max(f(x)/g(x))" also gives me the error message

```
Error in if (x >= 0 & x <= pi/2) { : the condition has length > 1
```

As a result, I can't plot the histogram. Please help me fix the code!

Comment: Is M supposed to be a function or an object? If it is an object, what should be the value of x in M's calculation?

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez M is a multiplication constant.  Usually, I use the formula M <- max(f(x)/g(x)) to find the best value to give M, so that I have a high acceptance rate. But this doesn't always work.

Comment: So how are the M outside the rejection_sampling function and the M inside the rejection_sampling functions related?
As you copied it, rejection_sampling() requires a value M in this line: `if (u <= f(x)/(M*g(x)))`

Comment: In other words, if I define the "x" in M to value within the thresholds of functions `f` and `g`, i.e. `M <- max(f(pi*0.51)/g(pi*0.51))` your code works and I get a histogram.